# two postions on one straight line, find third postion further away

Tags: python, math, line

To the point directly, I have two coordinates on one straight line See pic 1 [pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UL5F.png)
But if I want to find another coordinate that are on the same line just further away, is there a Python pre created function that does that? or do I need to manually try and create one? If I need to create on, how can I do that? that basically takes two positions on the line, and in some way calculates a new on further down the line

Comment: A few things are unclear to me. First, do you want to find any other coordinate on that line? Or a specific one. Secondly, in what format are your coordinates?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you have the coordinates of 2 points on a straight line you can calculate the equation of that line. You use this equation to find another point further down the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have line with points `p1=(x1,y1)` and `p2=(x2, y2)`, then any point on the line might be represented in  form:

```
 x = x1 + (x2 - x1) * t
 y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * t
```

For value of `t`  in range `0..1` point lies inside segment `p1p2`, for `t<0 and t>1` point lies on continuation of line. So choose needed value of `t` to place new point properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to basically implement the equation of a line in a vector form. It can be written as, for any point `p` on this ray (or a line) with origin `Op` and a unit direction vector `d` for length `l` along the ray from `Op`

`p = Op + d*l`

you can make numpy arrays for `p`, `Op` and `d` while `l` is a scalar.

for the image that you shared you can consider

```
Op = np.array([2,5])
d = np.array([5,9])-Op
d = d/np.norm(d)
```

with this you can get `p` for different values of `l`